# Attaching [UInt8] as data to alamofire

Tags: swift, http, byte, alamofire

I am trying to uploading some bytes to a server using alamofire, my code is as follows:

```
let parameters: Parameters = ["data": data]
let headers: HTTPHeaders = ["Content-Type": "application/vnd.awallet-signed-orders-v0"]

    Alamofire.request(query, method: .put,
                      parameters: parameters,
                      encoding: JSONEncoding.default,
                      headers: headers).responseJSON { response in
        print("Request: \(String(describing: response.request))")   // original url request
        print("Response: \(String(describing: response.response))") // http url response
        print("Result: \(response.result)") // response serialization result

        if let json = response.result.value {
            let parsedJSON = try! JSON(parseJSON: (json as! String))
            callback(parsedJSON["orders"]["accepted"])
        }

        if let data = response.data, let utf8Text = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
            print("Data: \(utf8Text)") // original server data as UTF8 string
        }
    }
}
```

The data is a [UInt8] however doing this makes alamofire cast the bytes as a string, if the array is [0,0] it becomes "0,0", this is not what I want as I want it to upload the bytes directly.

Is there a way to do this in alamofire?

**Note: I don't want to cast it to a hex string as this is not efficient**

Answer (score 0):

Solved, just need to use the upload method and convert bytes to data

```
var hexMessageData = signedOrders[0].message

let headers: HTTPHeaders = ["Content-Type": "application/vnd.awallet-signed-orders-v0"]

Alamofire.upload(Data(bytes: hexMessageData), to: query, method: .put, headers: headers).response { response in
   if let data = response.data, let utf8Text = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
            print("Data: \(utf8Text)") // original server data as UTF8 string
            callback(data.hexEncoded)
        }
    }
```